# How to get media_id of a post from permalink using Instagram API?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I am trying to obtain `media_id` from the permalink of an Instagram post.

I know that there exists:

```
GET https://graph.facebook.com/{api-version}/?fields=business_discovery.username(username){media,id}&access_token={access-token}
```

This lets me get `media_id` for all latest posts from a specific account.

But that does not help me as I need to get `media_id` for any particular post instead of any account as my objective is to get `media_url` of any post using its `media_id`.

Also, I could not find anything related in the official Facebook/Instagram API documentation.

Comment: If you have just the URL of an Instagram post, I don't believe there is a way to essentially translate the ID to the actual Media ID.